# Browser close event confirm. On clicking ok run some code, custom code

Tags: events, browser

When users closes the browser, I want to confirm "do you want to logout?".
If yes, I want to run some logging-off code and show message "you are logged off". If no, just do nothing.

Below is the code I am using:

```
window.onbeforeunload = closeit; 

function closeit(e) {
    var closeEvent = false;
    if (event.clientY < 0)
        closeEvent = true;

    if ((closeEvent)) {


      var response = confirm("Are you sure you want to log-off?");

        if(response == true){
            var swf = "SWFAPP";
            var container;
            if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") >= 0)
            {
                container = document;
            }
            else
            {
                container = window;
            }
            container[swf].logOutUser();
            alert("Logged off");
        }
        else{

        }

     }
 }
```

The above code is not working, its closing the browser no matter if I click OK or CANCEL. If OK is clicked its not throwing alert message "Logged off".

If I remove the confirm line and say response is always true, it runs the log-off code and shows the message "Logged off". Container.logOutUser updates the user status in DB.

Comment: You could try `if( confirm("Are you...") )` instead of creating the middle variable. `confirm()` returns true or false, but I always get confused with which `==` or `=` to use, etc. So simply IF( confirm() ) should work if your IF (true) works.

Answer (score 0):

The `onbeforeunload` event don't have `clientY` property, so `closeEvent` will always be `false`.

Event's `returnValue` property must be set to prevent page unload, but browser holds the inal decision by prompting user. See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeunload

```
window.onbeforeunload = closeit; 

function closeit(e) {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to log-off?")) {
        var container;
        if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") >= 0)
        {
            container = document;
        }
        else
        {
            container = window;
        }
        container[swf].logOutUser();
        alert("Logged off");
    }
    else{
        e.returnValue='Log-off cancelled.';
    }
}
```

Comment: The above snippet dint work either. It closes browser on yes and no.

Comment: What browser are you using? The code was tested in Firefox v14 with an empty HTML and with no third party scripts.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (evt) { 
 evt = window.event;
alert(evt.clientY);
```